# Xamarin android - mvvmcross binding button image property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am new to mvvmcross. In my xamarin android app, I want to change a buttons background image when the user clicks on it. I am not sure how this binding can be done. Can some one help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind any background image with DrawableId and DrawableName:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="DrawableId TheIntOfTheResource; Click SomeCommand" />
```

In SomeCommand you can change the id of TheIntOfTheResource which you bind to, so the image gets changed.